# Casting to undeclared type

Tags: templates, c++11, std

The idea is identical to the generic version of [`GetComponent()` in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html). But I'm currently stumbling on the following template issue:

```
template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> MyClass::GetMyComponent()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _baseTypeList.size(); i++)
    {
        auto base = _baseTypeList[i];
        T* check = dynamic_cast<T*>(base.get());
        if (check)
        {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(base);
        }
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(nullptr);
}
```

where `_baseTypeList` is a `std::vector<std::shared_pntr{MyBaseType}>` types.

In this function, I am iterating over a list of components to find if there is one that matches the type I'm asking for. if there is one, return the component cast to that type. Otherwise return a `nullptr`.

However, when I call this function from outside code, I get the following error:

```
error C2680: 'MyType*' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast
```

where `MyType` is some class that derives from component.

When I put `#include "MyType.h"` in the header it compiles just fine but without it it gives this error and doesn't compile.

This means I cannot use it in other classes without modifying the header file this template class resides in, which will be a problem for me.

Is there a way I can achieve simular results without having to `#include` every single header of the type I pass in the template for?

[EDIT]
For clarity, consider a person using my library, he creates a type 
"Foo : MyBaseType" where MyBaseType has a virtual method "Update" that is called every frame.
any instance of class MyBaseType (including Foo) is to be managed by this library, and have update called every frame.
This library thus has a large list of "MyBaseType" objects. But has no knowledge of the actual type they are, just that they derive from "MyBaseType", so it can call Update() on them.

If I need a specific type the library needs to be able to search for it in this list and return it.
I would like this "search" to happen in the library itself, so I do not have to expose the list, and write a new "search" method for every type that derives from "MyBaseType"

[FINAL]
It turned out I messed up the include order in my project.
a minimal example of what I was trying to do would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "vector"

class MyBaseClass
{
    virtual void Update(){};
};

class MyLibrary
{
public:
    template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyBaseClass>> list;
};

template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> MyLibrary::GetComponent()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<MyBaseClass, T>::value, "T1 is no subclass of ModelComponent");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        auto comp = list[i];
        T* check = dynamic_cast<T*>(comp.get());
        if (check)
        {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(comp);
        }
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(nullptr);
}

class MyClass : public MyBaseClass
{
    void Update() override;
};

void MyClass::Update()
{

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyLibrary lib;
    lib.list.push_back(std::make_shared<MyClass>());
    auto var = lib.GetComponent<MyClass>();
    std::cout << (var ? "var is object" : "var is not") << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

which works as expected.

The primary issue was that the compiler gave an error in the "GetMyComponent" function, so I found a usage of it that did everything as suggested.

But it turned out there was a second usage that did not have the definition of "MyClass" before calling it (but didn't give an error, as it was forward declared in its header file).

Comment: What use is `shared_ptr<MyType>` to a caller that doesn't have a definition of `MyType`? Anyway, you cannot `dynamic_cast` or, for that matter, `static_cast` a `MyBaseType*` to `MyType*` without knowing how the two relate to each other. You appear to claim that `MyType` derives from `MyBaseType` - but how is the compiler supposed to know that, if not by seeing the contents of `"MyType.h"`?

Comment: The caller does have a defenition of "MyType". A library i am making simply exposes this function. This library has only knowledge of "MyBaseType", where "MyType" is some user defined class that derives from "MyBaseType". Though it would be unfortunate if this was indeed not possible

Comment: You don't need to `#include "MyType.h"` in the header that defines `MyClass::GetMyComponent`. You do need to include it in the source file that calls `MyClass::GetMyComponent<MyType>()`. Is that really too much to ask? [Live example](http://rextester.com/VJH95253)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the definition of possible `T` types included into your *header*.  You do need the relevant one defined in the *translation unit* in which the template is expanded:

```
// client.cpp
#include <myclass.h>
#include <foo.h>  // defines class Foo

void f(MyClass *p)
{
    auto c = p->GetMyComponent<Foo>();
    c->foobar();
}
```

Comment: and yes, this is exactly what i am doing.
    `auto myvar= MyClass*->GetMyComponent<MyType>();`

i am not including any types in my header, just the function i posted.

it is however the compiler telling me i have to add "MyType" to the header, otherwise it wont compile

Comment: @Brian: It's hard to tell quite what you're doing.  Could you please edit your question so that the example is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](/help/mcve)?  I'm not convinced you have your equivalent of my `#include <foo.h>` above; a MCVE may help me reproduce your problem and give a better answer.

Comment: Oh, and include your compiler's error messages.  I doubt it's telling you  to add an include _to the header_, merely the location where the type is used.